# Insert Text in HTML Input / Textarea at Specified Position

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In AngularJS, how do we insert a text, for example, I Want to insert text at position 7 with word "My "

Before

```
<textarea type="text">This is Text</textarea>
```

After

```
<textarea type="text">This is My Text</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
    $scope.text = $scope.insertText('This is Text', ' My', 7);

    $scope.insertText = function(source, text, position) {
        var subStr = source.substring(0, position);

        return subStr + text + source.substring(subStr.length);
    }

   <textarea type="text">{{text}}</textarea>
```

Comment: Hi Allabakash, it's working, I couldn't find that when searching, thank you :)